# Playframework pushing to Websocket

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka-stream

I read through the WebSocket documentation of Play Framework, but haven't found the solution to my problem.

## Problem description

I have an API (Play Framework) which receives data from Client 1 (C1) through a POST event. I have an other client that should then get automatically updated, if it is listening (read: has an open WebSocket to the API). How can I push the received data into the Websocket?

The documentation of the Play Framework only shows how to *react* to a received message through a Websocket, but not how to send data from the server.

### Expectations for the solution

Could you please make a simple example for such a behavior? Maybe we can get it included in the documentation of Play Framework. I don't have a lot of experience with Akka.

### Further Information

There are two ways of working with Websockets in Play Framework. One is with actors and the other is directly with Akka Streams. I think Akka Streams could be more straight-forward in this case, but I can live with both ways (or maybe a third one?).

**If you need more information, just comment below!**

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your clients like this:

First, In the routes file:

```
GET     /connectWebSocket           @myPackage.myController.webSocket
```

Then, your controller:

```
def webSocket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { _ =>
  ActorFlow.actorRef(ActorReceivingMessagesFromPost.props())
}
```

After, you create an actor that receives messages from posts with a receive like this:

```
class ActorReceivingMessagesFromPost(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg: String => out ! msg
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need more informations

Comment: I am working with Java, but I can still comprehend your solution (mostly). But I don't see how you tell the actor something from the POST action. I have an action `addData(data)` that gets called through a POST route. I want to push the `data`, *if* there is an actor handling the `WebSocket`.

Comment: In your addData action, send a message to the actor ActorReceivingMessagesFromPost. You should probably create it when the application starts (with bindActor), and send it a message with   val actor: ActorSelection = actorSystem.actorSelection(actorPath) and send a message with actor ! "msg"